# Android OpenGL.ES Texture/Image Drawing

Tags: android, image, canvas, opengl-es

I have recently started into learning OpenGL ES, learning from 1.0, working to 2.0.

My question is this, I know how to render two triangles(sharing one vertex coordination) to create a square/rectangle. And adding a texture to that, the size of the image. To seamlessly create an image on the 'canvas'. 
Is this the correct way of putting a graphic image on the screen, or is there a method that I can use to put one on?

In other words: Android API has::

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, filter);
```

Does OpenGL ES 1.0+ or 2.0 have a separate method to place a Bitmap image on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no. There are a couple of extensions that more directly support functionality similar to what you're describing:

http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_draw_texture.txt
http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/draw_texture.txt

But with standard API calls, what you're describing is the right way to display an image.

OpenGL ES 3.0 has `glBlitFramebuffer()`, which is another option that could be used for this. But this is not in ES 1.1 and ES 2.0.

Full OpenGL used to have a `glDrawPixels()` function, but this is also deprecated in modern OpenGL versions.

Comment: Thanks man, I was planning to go to the official site soon, but want to finish this dinosaur of a book to just get my head started in the right direction.